# How to excetute a SQL BETWEEN command in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework

Just as the title says, I want something in the likes of:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE YEAR BETWEEN 2011 AND 2005;
```

Any help here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `BETWEEN` syntax in linq. So you might have to use something like this:

```
var result=(
   from t in db.TABLE
   where t.YEAR>=2005 && t.YEAR=<2011
   select t 
);
```

Where db is the linq data context

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a `BETWEEN` command in sql, but you can always do something like

```
where year >= 2005 AND year <= 2011
```